# Expanding paths in Bash variables into sed expressions

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to ask what's wrong with this line?

```
sed -i "/$PWD/a\ Hello World" historia.txt
```

when I had it in this `''` except for `""` it was working, of course without expanded variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the paths contain `/` characters, and that character you used in `sed` as well for the substitution arguments separation. The simplest solution is to just use another separator in `sed`, one does not appear in your data (say a `|`, or, as in my subsequent example, a comma):

```
sed -i "s,${PWD},a Hello World," historia.txt
```

Edit: Above explains the problem you have (the conflicting slashes). But I see (now) that you are not substituting but adding a line after the matching line. In this case you could escape the slashes in the `PWD` path for `sed`, e.g. by:

```
sed -i "/${PWD//\//\\/}/a Hello World" historia.txt
```

Comment: You should be able to use alternate address delimiters for commands other than the `s` command: however they need to be introduced with a backslash e.g. `"\,$PWD,a\ Hello World"`

Comment: Good to know. - Now I just wonder about the added leading space; could it be that he wants the data added to the matching line? In this case he'd need `sed -i "\,${PWD},s,$, Hello World," historia.txt`.

Comment: If the OP doesn't want the leading space, then just `"\,$PWD,a\Hello World"` should do it

Comment: Sure. In my previous comment I meant that the single space could be an indicator for a different requirement (append to matching line vs. append a new line after matching line). - But meanwhile the question is accepted, so everything seems to be fine anyway.

Comment: Note that `/` may not be the only character than needs escaping. All the regular expression operators would as well. Using `awk '1;index($0, ENVIRON["PWD"]){print "Hello World"}'` instead (or `awk '1;$0 == ENVIRON["PWD"]{print "Hello World"}` if you want to match the full line instead of a substring) may be better.