# awk pattern with variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, quoting, variable

I have problem with command awk in bash
I want to find pattern with variable, but it doesn't work. Can you tell me what's wrong with this line?

```
awk -F" "  "/$PWD/ {print $1,$3}"  file.txt
```

Comment: double quote allow expansion of $1,$3 as well aw $PWD, try awk '/'$PWD'/ {print $1,$3}'

Comment: it says synax error

Comment: what is $PWD value ?

Comment: it's adress of directory

Comment: This is extremely similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190307/88983 where you received an answer that covers the reason why `$PWD` causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have been using double quotes, any `$`-variables will be expanded by bash before they reach awk. That's the first problem: `{ print $1, $3 }` will expand to `{ print , }`.

Next, the awk syntax you are trying to use is `/<regular expression>/ { <action> }`: the regular expression is not allowed to contain any unquoted slashes, but `$PWD` certainly contains some. That's the second issue.

You could try something like this instead:

```
"/${PWD//\//\\/}/ { print \$1, \$3 }"
```

This asks bash to replace any occurrences of `/` in `$PWD` with `\/`, and also escapes the `$` signs of `$1` and `$3` so that bash leaves them intact.

Comment: it still says syntax error

Comment: Then it would be interesting for us to know exactly where your awk thinks there is an error. I tried with GNU awk 4.0.1, successfully.

Comment: The syntax error is because you forgot a slash: `${PWD//\//\/}` should be `${PWD//\//\\/}`. I fixed it.

Comment: I tested the actual code that I posted, and the extra backslash should make no difference in this case (because it is within double quotes and does not precede a character with special meaning). Thanks for the edit anyway; doubling the backslash is probably less confusing.